# How can I display all the tables name in my database in a menustrip?

Tags: .net, database, visual-studio-2010, menu

I want to display all the table names that are in my database in a menustrip.

When I hover on the menu, list of all tables comes in a menu. When I click on a table name, that table will display on the datagridview with all the records in it. How can I do that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005095/can-i-get-name-of-all-tables-of-sql-server-database-in-c-sharp-application

Comment: execute "select * from sys.tables" then bind the result

Comment: Yea i did execute this query. and it works