# Check if table name exists SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-ce

How can I check if a table already exists before creating a new one?

Updated Code:

```
    private void checkTable()
            {

                string tableName = quotenameTxt.Text + "_" + firstTxt.Text + "_" + surenameTxt.Text;
                string connStr = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
             //   SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
            //    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { conn.Open(); }
                using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();    
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT * 
                                              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                                              WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tname", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tname", tableName);
        SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.Read()){
            MessageBox.Show("Table exists");}
        else{
            MessageBox.Show("Table doesn't exist");
createtable();}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Check if table exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/sql-server-check-if-table-exists)

Comment: is it necessary to have a table schema?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get name of all tables of SQL Server database in C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005095/can-i-get-name-of-all-tables-of-sql-server-database-in-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql Server Compact supports the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174156%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) views

```
using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();    
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT TOP 1 * 
                                          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                                          WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tname", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tname", tableName)
    SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read())
        Console.WriteLine("Table exists");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Table doesn't exist");

}
```

**EDIT**
In version 3.5 it seems that the TOP 1 instruction is not accepted. However, given the WHERE clause it should make no difference using it or not so, to make it work just change the query to

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                                      WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tname", conn);
```

**SECOND EDIT**
Looking at the code that creates the table.
(It is In chat, I suggest to add it to the question for completeness)

```
using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand( 
        "CREATE TABLE ['" + tableName + "'] " + 
        "(Weight INT, Name NVARCHAR, Breed NVARCHAR)", con))
```

The single quotes around the tableName variables becomes part of the name of the table. But the check for table exists doesn't use the quotes. And your code fall through the path that tries to create again the table with the quotes. Just remove the quotes around the name. They are not needed.

Comment: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 12,Token in error = 1 ] is the error i get from this code

Comment: I have no error testing with a database with Sql Server Compact 4.0

Comment: Well, I cannot test with 3.5 now. But try to remove the `TOP 1` and leave only `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ....` this should be absolutely correct unless the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are not supported in 3.5.

Comment: Ok just downloaded and tested with the 3.5 bits. It is the TOP 1. Remove it and it should work fine

Comment: I've done as you said but its not actually doing anything. Regardless of whether the table exists it just gives me the "table does not exist" messagebox.

Comment: Consider that |DataDirectory| substitution string resolves in <projectfolder>\bin\debug in a winforms application. Are you checking against the correct database? Are you using the parameter as shown in my example or are you using the string concatenation as you have done in your code.

Comment: Well, I cannot find any reason for this code to not work (of course if the table really exists). Remember that this works on the database present in your BIN\DEBUG or BIN\x86\DEBUG folder, not on the database in the project folder.

Comment: I know, but for existing tables, those that are already in the database (created from the server explorer function) it isn't saying they exist

Comment: What are these names not found? An example of an existing name could help

Comment: customersTBL (created in the server explorer)

Comment: Ahh! I forgot im using a string, so the table called customersTBL does exist, but the table called "customersTBL_example_text" does. Schoolboy error.

Comment: Now its not recognising that I'm creating new tables (create a table, exit debug, enter debug, enter the same details and it says it doesn't exist, then gives me an error in the createtable class (called in if the table doesnt exist) saying the table exists.

Comment: I am lost. Please if the original question is resolved then I suggest to choose an answer as the accepted one and then post a new question with the new problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56037/discussion-between-user3521452-and-steve).

Comment: Your problem is the "CREATE TABLE ['" + tablename + "'] ..... ". In this way if you have tablename = "MyTable" you create a table with the name 'MyTable' with the quotes that are part of the name. Then you test for the table without the quotes

Comment: i believe that has cured it. Thanks @Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SqlClientConnection to get list of all objects in the db.

```
private void checkTable()
{
    string tableName = quotenameTxt.Text + "-" + firstTxt.Text + "-" + surenameTxt.Text;
    string connStr = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";

    using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr))
    {
        bool isTableExist = conn.GetSchema("Tables")
                                .AsEnumerable()
                                .Any(row => row[2] == tableName);
    }

    if (!isTableExist)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No such data table exists!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Such data table exists!");
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3005157/1271037

Comment: "Specified method is not supported"

Comment: GetSchema added in version 4.0 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172417(v=sql.110).aspx