# Get active datagrid's name upon cell editing event?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have been trying to get the active datagrid's name upon a cell editing event.

Firstly, I don't know if this is a good practice, but I have a event that runs when a datagrid's cell is edited. I then am trying to test if the user added a row to the table. I want a way to see which Table is being edited so as I can put in an if clause to direct it to the correct code so it won't throw an error.

```
private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {

            Staff_Time_TBL selectedRow = e.Row.Item as Staff_Time_TBL;
            long id = selectedRow.ID;

            if (id == -1)
            {
                // give a GUID and then insert it into the database when saved
                selectedRow.ID = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
                sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.InsertOnSubmit(selectedRow);
            }

            try
            {
                sql.SubmitChanges();
                LastSavedTextBlock.Text = "Last saved: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Alerts.Error("Couldn't save changed to the database", "Database Error", ex);
            }
        }
```

At present, obviously if this table in the code below is not accessed it throws an error,

```
Staff_Time_TBL selectedRow = e.Row.Item as Staff_Time_TBL;
                long id = selectedRow.ID;
```

My attempts at getting the datagrid's name, this just returns `DataGrid`

```
var tblName = sender.GetType().Name;
```

And this returns `null` for the variable `tblName2` and throws an exception on the last line due to that.

```
string dataGridName = "";             
            DataObject tblName2 = sender as DataObject;
            dataGridName = tblName2.ToString();
```

There is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005095/can-i-get-name-of-all-tables-of-sql-server-database-in-c-sharp-application) that gets all tables names and [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server?rq=1) that checks to see if one exists, but I can't find anything of how to get the `sender` datagrid's name.

Obviously if this is not good practise I would like to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx) class :

```
private void Dgrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement source = e.EditingElement;

            while (!(source is DataGrid))
                source = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source) as FrameworkElement;

            MessageBox.Show(((DataGrid)source).Name);
        }
```

Comment: Will this throw an error if it is not a datagrid? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is the name of the data grid you want, this should work.

```
DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;  // Will throw an exception if not a DataGrid
string name = dg.Name;
```

Not sure why you use DataObject.

Comment: Datagrid was not in intellisense. That what I figured I needed, but b/c it was not there, I through a whole heap of controls and objects to that. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Now that I realize you can do that, to get around the exception you could do this, `DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
            if (dg != null)
            {
                string dgName = dg.Name;
            }`

Comment: It all depends on if you want the exception or not. Sometimes you do, sometimes you don't.